# Ember.js: how to handle click that occurred in top-level view?

Tags: ember.js

The question is rather simple: how to send event to the current controller when click happened outside of its view?

Here is an JSBin illustrating the idea http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pebilujera/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is called ClickElsewhereMixin

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it exactly like you asked, try the `needs` approach: [Managing Dependencies between Controllers](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

Comment: hello thriqon, I added the jsbin to illustrate the question, should prevent the XY question :)

Comment: There might be a better way. Is it absolutely neccessary for the clickable area to be controlled by the application? You can render a view belonging to another route via the `renderTemplate` hook.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: looks like a different case - I'm building something resembles http://daviferreira.github.io/medium-editor/ and the task is to hide panel if user anywhere except that panel.

Comment: and actually I would like to mimic an original medium.com behavior